# How use if condition for nullable boolean in linq to NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, nullable, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a `Person` class that `Sex` property is nullable.

```
public class Person 
{
    public bool? Sex {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a query by linq to NHibernate.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Person>();

if (dto.Sex != null)
    q = q.Where(p => p.Sex == dto.Sex);

return q.ToList();
```

Now if value of dto.Sex equals `true`, result is correct.

But if value of dto.Sex equals `false` result is not correct because result is contain persons that Sex is false or null.

I checked profiler for this query:

```
select * from Person_Person person0_
where  case
             when person0_.Sex = 1 then 1
             else 0
           end = case
                   when 0 /* @p0 */ = 1 then 1
                   else 0
                 end
```

Why?

Comment: I checked this example becuase i didn't realize of that problem, and i can say that he really exists hym some workaround: .Where(x => x.IsActive.HasValue && x.IsActive == false)

Comment: @Adam: I khow it, but I look for for better solution

Comment: You wrote in comment "My base problem is in type of generated query" can you elaborate on this point. As I see the described problem exists only with bool type.

Comment: @Adam: My problem is both. My purpose in commenting was no use `Enum`.
I need to better solution for this problem, of course your solution is correct

Comment: I think you don't have any possibility to workaround this problem. For me nhibernate has bug, because he wrongly generate sql and I see 2 option: modified nhibernate code;) or use HasValue in Where statement

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that LINQ query generates a case statement, that's really weird...

But I personally don't like the approach of a nullable boolean.

A boolean has 2 values, true or false. The moment you make it nullable you're giving it a 3rd possible value.

In a scenario like this I think it's better to use an Enum.

I assume 'Sex' is for 'Male' / 'Female', in which case I think a better approach to the problem is an enum like:

```
public enum SexEnum
{
   Unspecified = 0,
   Male = 1,
   Female = 2
}
```

It makes your code much more descriptive as well:

```
var males = session.Query<Person>().Where(x => x.Sex == SexEnum.Male);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But `Sex` property in this question is for example. My base problem is in type of generated query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in nhibernate linq provider, and a workaround for it will be like this:

```
if (dto.Sex != null)
    q = q.Where(p => p.Sex == dto.Sex && p.Sex != null);
```

The trick is to filter out nullable values from the set which should contain false values or true values (true values has no issue so this is mainly for the false values)